# Why use React Helmet Library if I can modify the meta tags in the public/index.html file?

Tags: reactjs, seo, react-helmet

`react-helmet` is a library that is used to set titles and metadata to a react app for SEO. As it turns out. I can also directly modify the `index.html` in the `public` folder of my react application for providing meta tags and title for my React Application. Then, what is the point of React Helmet.

**Here are my Questions regarding SEO with react-helmet ?**

- What extra options does `react-helmet` provide which cannot be achieved by directly modifying `index.html` ?
- Can I use `react-helmet` to for statically rendering `h1` tags and `alts` attributes in the body of my application ?

Comment: I imagine the primary benefit is to manage the `<head>` elements within the React application, including any dynamic content managed within that application, as opposed to statically editing your `index.html` file.  If the latter approach works for your needs then perhaps you don't need this tool.

Comment: Are you referring to the ["Server usage"](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#server-usage) ? Then I suggest to make that clear in your question. Apart from that, [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) can change the HTML `<head>` dynamically, and keeps it valid, e.g. manages duplicate tags.